# C++: Notations like "cv1 A", "cv2 B", "cv12 A"

Tags: c++

What do notations like "cv1 A", "cv2 B", "cv12 A" mean? I can't understand

Comment: It's impossible to tell without some context. Where do `cv1` come from?

Comment: You need to post some code. Where did you see this? What was the context?

Answer (score 2):

`cv` us a notation commonly used to point out that the type can be marked as `volatile` or `const`.

Comment: But doesn't make that much sense in this context, does it? I mean `const volatile 1` isn't meaningful at all [nor `const` AND `volatile` at the same time, except for very rare cases]

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ standard, `cv` refers to the `const` and `volatile` qualifiers of the type in question. `cv A` is shorthand for "`A` and whatever `const` and `volatile` qualifiers it has". Adding a number (`cv1`, `cv2`) is just a mechanism for saying that there are possibly different sets of cv qualifiers involved.